# Объединение 2х таблиц в 1 "зубчатую" SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server

MS SQL Server 2017

1 таблица :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2 таблица :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно получить :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Пробовал делать разные виды джоинов, но всё сводится к декартову произведению, с созданием большого количества повторений.

Comment: Как вариант можно создать модель, которая будет принимать только уникальные данные ( string string List<string> List<string>), но хорошо бы обойтись меньшей кровью.
PS таблица 1 и 2 изначально хранятся в нормальной форме - это уже продукт ряда джоинов.

Comment: Пробовали объединить(UNION) все продукты с городами из обоих таблиц, и потом сджоинить с обеями таблицами по LEFT...

Comment: У вас проблема со схемой данных. Возьмем к примеру Огурцы из Краснодара - их привезли Поставщик1 и Поставщик2 и свалили в одну кучу на складе. Потом пришли Покупатель1 и Покупатель2 и купили сколько-то там этих огурцов из кучи. Каким образом можно определить кто из них от какого поставщика купил огурцы? С текущей схемой данных - никак, потому что, чтобы это понять, куч на складе должно быть две.

Comment: У меня нет задачи для последующего сопоставления и хранения в таблице типа Orders. Это чисто запрос для вывода информации пользователю.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо [@skingreek](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1030150/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-2%d1%85-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86-%d0%b2-1-%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%8e-sql-server-2017#comment1753606_1030150) за подсказку!
UNION с добавлением null столбца в каждой таблице, помог привести к объединённой таблице с уникальными значениями в Consumer и Supplier, а далее уже обработать и получить то что нужно в C#.